# Why I see so many auth.androidauthorizeapp 408 error (The proxied app is not already installed)?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I've developed an Android app, and when I check the API Error Breakdown, I see auth.androidauthorizeapp error 408's failure rate is 44%. I think it's too high.

Can someone tell me what I can do to fix this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I opened a bug through developer.facebook.com to report this issue. They accepted, but so far it's not fixed.